# Remove-item foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove folders in a path using Powershell (sharepointFilesUpdate.ps1).  It seems to work locally but gets wonky when trying to execute it for multiple Onedrive folders. It works well for one file but not for multiple files.  (I'm a complete PowerShell noob)

```
$path = gci -Path  'c:\Users\myusername\orgnaization\Folder'

foreach ($items in $path){
Remove-Item c:\Users\myusername\organization\Folder\$items\SubfolderIWantDeleted\}
```

I get this error:

```
Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'of'.
At C:\Users\myusername\organization\Folder\sharepointFilesUpdate.ps1:8 char:5
+     Remove-Item c:\Users\myusername\organization ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

I'd like for the script to remove the specified subfolders in a list of parent folders

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could  you please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah.  I tried quotes and I tried "-Recurse" and "-Force -Recurse"

Comment: Yes.  The $items in the directory path is supposed to cycle threw each folder name I intend to change

Comment: You think the "ps1:8 char:5" is indicating an encoding issue?  If so, How would I declare my encoding in a ps1 file?

Comment: I tried to share the code without divulging my username and organization

Comment: Here is another shot...(I'm new to the platform).  Please forgive me if it is a little wonky.   $path = gci -Path 'c:\Users\myusername\organization\Test Security Files - Documents\' | foreach ($items in $path){Remove-Item c:\Users\myusername\organization\Test Security Files - Documents\$items\SY21-22}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove particular subfolder underneath a given path you simply use `Remove-Item` like this:

```
Remove-Item -Path 'c:\Users\myusername\orgnaization\Folder\*\sy21-22' -Recurse -Force
```

If it's about the subfolders you may use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\Users\myusername\orgnaization\Folder\*\sy21-22' -Directory | 
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: I'm attempting to remove a specific subfolder named "sy21-22" from a large number of parent folders with different names.  Its seems if I use the first example, I'd delete all of my different-named parent folders

Comment: See my updated answer. 

Comment: IT WORKED for a nice amount of them!!! Got a few errors about saying "Could not find a part of the path 'blahblahblah.xlsx'  " and one that says "WriteError:blahblahblah.xlsx:FileInfo"

Comment: And an IOException

Comment: Are some of the paths longer than 260 characters? You may enable long path support then. [Enable long path support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) ... and you should have proper access to files. ☝

Comment: You know...I think you're right.  But its my work computer I don't have key registry permissions.  Thanks though.  You got me a lot further than I did on my own

Comment: So you may ask your IT department for help if that's something you need for your work.  ‍♂️